# use sql file in "\copy" psql command line

Tags: bash, postgresql, export-to-csv, psql

I'm trying to script a query from a bash file but the select query is in a file. For compatibility and test, I'd like to keep it this way.

In short I'd like to write something like:

```
psql -c data_base "\copy (<file.sql>) To './test.csv' With CSV"
```

Would you know how to do that ?

**EDIT**

The "file.sql" contains a query :

```
$cat file.sql
$SELECT country FROM world;
```

Comment: Your requirement is not clear. Can you explain it with a sample input and an expected output.

Comment: The <file.sql> isn't a real sequence. It 's the file containing the query, i'm trying to pass it to the \copy command.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `bash` substitution as,

```
psql -c data_base "\copy ($(<file.sql)) To './test.csv' With CSV"
```

`$(<file)` expands the contents of the `file`

Comment: I have added parentheses because those those are needed when you use a query with `COPY`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: Appreciate it! Cheers!

Comment: still testing, ;-) There's issue with a more complex query ( containing parentheses or quotes )

Comment: This was very helpful and worked perfectly for me, thanks

Comment: I tried the same with `$(<file)`. I am getting `-bash: /usr/bin/psql: Argument list too long`

Edit: My command 
`psql -h DB_HOST DB_NAME DB_USER -c "\copy ($(</tmp/prod_get_carrier_tier_dbcfg.sql)) To './test1.csv' With CSV"`

Comment: @kartikmaji yes I get the same thing - I was hoping to find a solution that passes the file to psql rather than the contents