# How to pass sql file in "\copy" psql command line

Tags: postgresql, psql

I am trying to find a way to pass a file to psql while using '\copy'. There is a question posted here [use sql file in "\copy" psql command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42065299/use-sql-file-in-copy-psql-command-line) asking a similar thing, but the accepted solution doesn't actually pass a file to psql, it passes the contents of the file, so this cannot be done when the contents of the sql file exceeds the maximum allowed length of the psql command.

e.g. something like this `psql -c data_base "\copy \file_path <file.sql> To './test.csv' With CSV"`

Answer (score 0):

Using copy rather than \copy, you can do it like this:

```
(echo "copy ("; cat file.sql ; echo ") to STDOUT with CSV")| psql -X > ./test.csv
```